# Transcribing Take It To The Head By Dj Khaled

Tags: chord-theory, transcription, voice-leading

[image: gyazo 1 highlights]I know you all are pitch-perfect, and can literally discern the note of a hi-hat being played next to white noise so I had some questions about transcribing the highlighted areas on the gyazo links.. what are the voice of the note leading in the highlighted areas. and what are the notes to the highlighted notes in the second gyazo link and, you can address it by color to make it more simple

if you listen to the link DJ Khaled take it to the head to the remake reference you can hear if I might be missing any extra voice leadings to the chords? if there are any tweaks (detuned notes extra notes or slides) I might need to add to the intro chorus chords or verse let me know.

the reference I'm going off of shows very limited info from what I need to complete this remake

original version

reference I'm going off of

highlighted areas https://gyazo.com/9988aaf68b0dc32235d292abdf509fc3 https://gyazo.com/cd5190bff919134b9a6446a23b4214a8

[image: gyazo 2 highlights]

Comment: The help center states that this isn't a site for transcription questions.

Comment: I wonder if there is a site where people can do transcriptions collaboratively.